# How to convert a shapefile into a graph in which use Dijkstra

Tags: python, shapefile, graph, dijkstra

I am working in a simulation using NetLogo, the idea is to make the agents interact inside the roads of a simplified city, in order to  do that I need to use some algorithms to find the fastest path between two points in the city (for example Dijkstra or A*), and to do that I need to work with a graph of the city (with nodes and vertices) but I don't know how to convert the shapefile into a graph.

My idea was to get all the intersections between two streets and start building the graph connecting those nodes. I have tried `networkx` for python but I had some problems installing the library `gdal`. Currently I'm using the `s2g` library ([here](https://github.com/caesar0301/s2g)) to do it, but for example for a shp file like this

[image: example shapefile]

I always get this:

```
INFO:root:Validating pair-wise line connections of raw shapefiles (total 3 lines)
100% (3 of 3) |##########################################################################################################| Elapsed Time: 0:00:00 Time: 0:00:00
Major components statistics:
    Total components: 0
    Component size: max 0, median 0.0, min 0, average 0.0
    Top comp. sizes: 0
```

I suppose that is an empty graph so I cannot work with it. Perhaps there is a better approach to my problem or an easy tool to convert shp to graphs. I mac user so I have no access to spatialite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [sg](https://github.com/caesar0301/s2g) module uses [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) to read the shapefiles (see [shapegraph.py](https://github.com/caesar0301/s2g/blob/master/s2g/shapegraph.py)
) and if you can use the module, therefore Fiona is installed.

If you cannot use [nx_shp.py](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/6e20b952a957af820990f68d9237609198088816/networkx/readwrite/nx_shp.py) (because of osgeo) and you have problems with [sg](https://github.com/caesar0301/s2g), you can use Fiona and [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) to create a Networkx Graph. ([GSE: How to calculate edge length in Networkx](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213431) for example).

```py
from shapely.geometry import shape
import fiona
geoms =[shape(feature['geometry']) for feature in fiona.open("stac_graphe.shp")]
import itertools
# create a Graph
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
for line in geoms:
   for seg_start, seg_end in itertools.izip(list(line.coords),list(line.coords)[1:]):
    G.add_edge(seg_start, seg_end)
```

Result

[image]

You can also create a [Planar Graph](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/102792/2581)

```
from shapely.ops import unary_union
res = unary_union(geoms)
G = nx.Graph()
for line in res:
    for seg_start, seg_end in itertools.izip(list(line.coords),list(line.coords)[1:]):
        G.add_edge(seg_start, seg_end)
```

[image]

#### New

There is a problem if some geometries are Multigeometries
For example:

```
 geoms =[shape(feature['geometry']) for feature in fiona.open("multiline.shp")]
 for line in geoms:
     print line
 MULTILINESTRING ((3 4, 10 50, 20 25), (-5 -8, -10 -8, -15 -4))
```

With geoms[0], you decompose the Multigeometry

```
 for line in geoms[0]:
     print line

 LINESTRING (3 4, 10 50, 20 25)
 LINESTRING (-5 -8, -10 -8, -15 -4)
```

Therefore the script becomes

```
  if line.geom_type== "MultiLineString":
        ....
   else:
```

Comment: Hi, I get this error running the first part of you answer `for seg_start, seg_end in itertools.izip(list(line.coords),list(line.coords)[1:]): ... in coords
    "Multi-part geometries do not provide a coordinate sequence")`, do you if there is workaround?

Comment: The easy solution is changing `for line in geoms:` to `for line in geoms[0]:`

Comment: You just have a MultiLineString geometry, look above in New

Comment: is there also a way to construct a planar weighted graph? I am loosing all my attributes with unary_union. See my question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/380054/95730

Comment: @gene from Python3 it is possible to use `zip` instaed of `itertools.izip`

Answer (score 0):

I should mention that using networkx, one may write or read a directional graph. Therefore, to create a planar graph you may change the code provided by "gene" to:

```
from shapely.ops import unary_union
res = unary_union(geoms)
G = nx.DiGraph()
for line in res:
    for seg_start, seg_end in itertools.izip(list(line.coords),list(line.coords)[1:]):
        G.add_edge(seg_start, seg_end)
        G.add_edge(seg_end, seg_start)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code not working because itertool don't have izip, the way to fix it is add:

```
try:
     from itertools import izip as zip
except ImportError: # will be 3.x series
     pass
```

and change itertools.izip by zip